# Resetting the value of a Input box in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following simple Angular app.

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Shopping</title>
    <script src="../js_libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1><span class="label label-default">{{title}}</span></h1>
    <br/>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Unit price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                <td>{{item.price}}</td>
                <td><input name="qty" type="text" ng-model="qty"/></td>
                <td>{{((item.price * qty) || 0) | number}}</td>
                <td><button ng-click="reset($index)">Reset</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

controller.js file:

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
$scope.title = 'Shopping Items';
$scope.items = [{title: 'Item1', price: 3.95},
                {title: 'Item2', price: 12.95},
                {title: 'Item3', price: 6.95}];
$scope.reset = function($index){

    $scope.qty[index] = "";
}
});
```

When I click a button from a row, the  value in Input box from that row (i.e. qty) should be 0, and also the column "Total price" should be modified to 0. But this is not happening ? What should I add ?

Comment: `$scope.reset = function($index){` -> this is your declaration, but you use `$scope.qty[index]` ;), remove the $ from function argument or add it to `index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qty` is not a key of the `object`, change model name to `item.qty` and while accessing it from array, refer `index` of the `object`

**Note:** Also consider typo at `[index]`, you are accepting argument as `$index` but while accessing the key, using `index`

**Suggestion:** `type='number'` for `<input>` is more appropriate for your use-case

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Shopping Items';
  $scope.items = [{
    title: 'Item1',
    price: 3.95
  }, {
    title: 'Item2',
    price: 12.95
  }, {
    title: 'Item3',
    price: 6.95
  }];
  $scope.reset = function(index) {
    $scope.items[index].qty = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1><span class="label label-default">{{title}}</span></h1>
  <br/>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Unit price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        <td>
          <input name="qty" type="number" ng-model="item.qty" />
        </td>
        <td>{{((item.price * item.qty) || 0) | number}}</td>
        <td>
          <button ng-click="reset($index)">Reset</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/q6Ltuc0c/1/)